# Apply click spinner only to one button - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, request, loading

I have a list in a table with button to view a PDF requested from server and I want to make a spinner until the document is received.
I made it to work, but when I click on a button, the spinner appears on all buttons, not only the one I clicked.

Angular

```js
            <button (click)="preview(key)">
              <div
                *ngIf="!this.isLoading"
              >
                <mat-icon>visibility</mat-icon>
                <p>View</p>
              </div>
              <mat-spinner
                *ngIf="this.isLoading"
                color="accent"
                [diameter]="20"
              ></mat-spinner>
            </button>
```

```js
  isLoading: boolean = false
  
    preview(key: any) {
    this.isLoading = true
    }
```

isLoading goes 'false' in another method when the document is received.

Comment: Where are the other buttons, Do you have a for loop somewhere?.
My educated guess is you have a for loop in the template, that renders multiple buttons. And for all these buttons you have only one state called 'isLoading'. When you toggle that boolean, it affects all buttons. The ideal solution would be to extract the list item to another component, with its on isLoading state.

Comment: Do not use snippets if they do not run.

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass an id to the preview function so that you can track which row has the spinner, then you will set the isLoading to that value! (you can use the row's index context property)

```html
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let key = index">
  <button (click)="loadingRow = key">
    <div *ngIf="!(loadingRow == key)">
      <mat-icon>visibility</mat-icon>
      <p>View</p>
    </div>
    <mat-spinner *ngIf="loadingRow == key"
      color="accent" [diameter]="20">
    </mat-spinner>
  </button>
</td>
```

```
loadingRow: number | null = null
```

then after the .pdf is loaded you have to return the flag 'loadingRow' to null